# How to have something print only once?

Tags: python

I'm unsure why it's taking my answer, and instead of continuing onto the next question, it repeats it once more before doing so?

Also, after the second question (there's only two), it shows them both in parentheses still? Please help me, thank you. ^_^

Here's the code by the way:

```
print (raw_input('What is your date of birth?')) 
y = raw_input('What is your date of birth?')
print ('Your date of birth is ' + y)
print (raw_input('What is your last name? '))
x = raw_input('What is your last name?')
print ('Your last name is ' + x)
print ('Your date of birth is ' + y, 'Your last name is ' +x)
```

I'm also using python 2.5.4.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Python?

Comment: I'm following this course on mit's site called intro to computer science and programming, and it says to use that version.

Comment: remove `print (raw_input())` lines

Comment: check out [this course](https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-6-00-1x-introduction-computer-2841) from edX. I'd be willing to bet they're using a more recent version. 2.5.4 was released in **2008**, and there have been many updates and bugfixes since then.

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input()` *itself* already prints the prompt. You are then *also* printing the return value of the `raw_input()` call. You then repeat the `raw_input()` function call *again*.

Remove the `print(raw_input(..))` lines; they are redundant:

```
y = raw_input('What is your date of birth?')
print 'Your date of birth is ' + y
x = raw_input('What is your last name?')
print 'Your last name is ' + x
```

Next, in Python 2, `print` is not a function, but a statement. You are treating it as one however, but Python sees the `(.., ...)` part (with a comma) as producing a *tuple*. Remove the parentheses:

```
print 'Your date of birth is ' + y, 'Your last name is ' + x
```

Now the whole line is part of the `print` statement as separate arguments for it, printing the two string results with a space in between.

Comment: Why not just `print 'blah', y, 'blah', x'`? :)